# Connecting to a local SQL Server database does not work in the setup exe application

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, exe

After installing my setup exe application on "Client PC", all process are worked correctly, but when I try to save some data on the application's local SQL Server database, this exception is thrown and I do not know what the problem is, as this exception never happens on my own PC.

Is there any requirement must be installed on the client PC?

The exception is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904)

[image: Exception]

The connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Appstore.Properties.Settings.StoringAppConnectionString"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StoringApp;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: The other PC has local database server? Can you share the connection string with sensitive information masked?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  Question is updated with the connection string

Comment: You are using sqlexpress. Is sqlexpress installed on the other computer too?

Answer (score 0):

You using a OBDC connection or something, make sure it's the same connection on the other PC compared to yours.

Comment: The error message clearly shows SqlClient, not ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

Error 26 generally means that your SQL Server instance is not reachable. Typically it is attributed to the fact that SQL Server service not running. Can you verify that once. Also if its on a different computer, you many need to turn on TCP/IP protocol. Make sure to also put ports TCP-1433 and UDP-1434 in firewall exception. Let me know if this works out.